# How to show modal after Ajax success?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After the article is successfully added, the modal showing the message should appear, but I'm just getting errors. So far this is my code:

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="icon-box">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE876;</i>
                </div>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Awesome!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">Your booking has been confirmed. Check your email for detials.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
        var text = String(f);
        var n=text.length;
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var docu_id = $('#docu_id').val();
        var hidden_snippet = $('#hidden_snippet').val();
        if (n!=0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/knowmore/index.php/ask_controller/book_add',
                data: {text:text,title: title,hidden_snippet: hidden_snippet,docu_id:docu_id},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#myModal").modal('show')
                    location.replace('/knowmore/index.php/index_controller/documentation/'+docu_id+'');
                }
            });
        } else { alert('Enter contents of the Article!'); }
    });
</script>
```

I used $("#myModal").modal('show') to show it but all I'm getting is an error saying modal is not a function.

Comment: modal is actually not a jquery function. just try $("#myModal").show();

Comment: You probably just want `$("#myModal").show()`

Comment: you are used bootstrap modal?

Comment: I'm assuming that is a bootstrap modal. Did you load bootstrap.min.js before the code you posted is executed? Also you forgot a semicolon right after $('#myModal').modal('show')

Comment: yes it is a bootstrap and I did include the js @M.Ruiz. I also tried doing all your answers but it's still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

It's because jQuery doesn't know any function named *modal* by default. If you want to show the modal you can just use *show()* function.

Change following

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#myModal").modal('show')
    location.replace('/knowmore/index.php/index_controller/documentation/' + docu_id + '');
}
```

into

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#myModal").show();
    location.replace('/knowmore/index.php/index_controller/documentation/' + docu_id + '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you all you need is to open a bootstrap modal, then just use 
    $('#myModal').modal();

Answer (score 0):

#### Write down the following code.

```
success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#myModel").modal("show");
     }
```